# Receiving a Type error code of #1009 on ActionScript3 in a "replay game" feature, how to solve this error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a University student and currently working on an assignment by myself to create a Flash game for Android using ActionScript 3 on Animate CC.

I'm a beginner at ActionScript 3 and have found myself stuck at the last bit of my game that I am creating.

On the game over screen of the game I have a button to allow the user to Play the game again (Restart Game) and this is where the problem occurs. The moment the play again button is being pressed and the game begins, everything's just frozen but the scoring system is running.

What I want to do is, when the user presses the "Play Again" button, that it will take him/her to the screen where it allows you to choose difficulty and just simply replay the game again.

This is the structure of how my game works:

- Intro screen (play button and instructions button)
- Pressing play button --> Choose Level screen
- Choose Level screen (easy or hard)
- If you press easy or hard it will go into the according difficulty game's screen
- Once you lose, it will then take you to the Game Over screen.
- Game Over screen has option of Play Again

These are some of the errors I'm receiving below:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
> object reference.     at
> AndroidSnowballShooterSanta_fla::MainTimeline/startGameInEasyMode()
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
> object reference.     at
> AndroidSnowballShooterSanta_fla::MainTimeline/moveSantaMCTowardMouse()
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
> object reference.     at
> AndroidSnowballShooterSanta_fla::MainTimeline/moveSantaMCTowardMouse()

The code I have used for the Game Over screen for enabling the function of replaying the game is this:

```
//Option button to let the user play Game again

playAgainButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, restartGame);
function restartGame(evt:MouseEvent)
{
     playAgainButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, restartGame);
     gotoAndPlay(1,"Choose Level");

---------------------------- 
//The code used in the Choose Level Screen looks like this

    stop();
    
    easyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, startGameInEasyMode);
    function startGameInEasyMode(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(1,"GameEasy");
         easyButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, startGameInEasyMode);
         
    }
    
    hardButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, startGameInHardMode);
    function startGameInHardMode(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(1, "GameHard");
         hardButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, startGameInHardMode);
         
    }
    
    DifficultiesBackButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, returnToHome);
    function returnToHome(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
         gotoAndPlay(1,"Intro");
          DifficultiesBackButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, returnToHome);
        
    }
    
    -------------------------------------
   
    
    //GAME EASY
    
    stop();
    
    import flash.events.Event;
    
    var myStartTime = getTimer();
    
    var bottomEdge = 0;
    var topEdge = 800;
    var leftEdge = 0;
    var rightEdge = 480;
    
    var SantaMCSpeed = 0.7;
    
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveSantaMCTowardMouse);
    function moveSantaMCTowardMouse(e:Event)
    {
        var angleInRad = Math.atan2((mouseY-SantaMC.y),(mouseX-SantaMC.x));
        SantaMC.rotation = (90 + angleInRad * 180/Math.PI);
    
        var distanceX = SantaMC.x - mouseX;
        var distanceY = SantaMC.y - mouseY;
        SantaMC.x -= (distanceX / 5) * SantaMCSpeed;
        SantaMC.y -= (distanceY / 5) * SantaMCSpeed;
    }
    
    // defining SnowCannonMC1
    SnowCannonMC1.x = 50;
    SnowCannonMC1.y = 800;
    SnowCannonMC1.pointing = "up";
    SnowCannonMC1.increment = 7;
    
    //moving Cannon 1
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSnowCannonMC1);
    function moveSnowCannonMC1(evt:Event)
    {
        if (SnowCannonMC1.x < leftEdge)
        {
            SnowCannonMC1.pointing = "right";
        }
        if (SnowCannonMC1.x > rightEdge)
        {
            SnowCannonMC1.pointing = "left";
        }
        if (SnowCannonMC1.pointing == "right")
        {
            SnowCannonMC1.x +=  SnowCannonMC1.increment;
        }
        else
        {
            SnowCannonMC1.x -=  SnowCannonMC1.increment;
        }
    
    }
    
    
    //making the Snow Cannons shoot at random
    var SnowCannonShootRate = 65;
    var snowBallMCCount = 0;
    
    var shootingSound = new cannonShotSound();
    
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shootSnowballCannon);
    function shootSnowballCannon(evt:Event)
    {
        var SnowCannonMC1ShootValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * SnowCannonShootRate);
        
        if (SnowCannonMC1ShootValue <= 1)
        {
            shoot(SnowCannonMC1);
        }
    }
    
    function shoot(aSnowBall)
    {
        shootingSound.play();
        snowBallMCCount++;
        var newSnowBallMC = root["snowBallMC" + snowBallMCCount]=this.addChild(new Snowball());
        
        newSnowBallMC.width = 19;
        newSnowBallMC.height = 19;
        
        newSnowBallMC.rotation = aSnowBall.rotation;
        newSnowBallMC.x = aSnowBall.x;
        newSnowBallMC.y = aSnowBall.y;
    }
    
    //moving snowBallMCs
    var score;
    var finalScore;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSnowBallMC);
    function moveSnowBallMC(evt:Event) {
        
    score = getTimer() - myStartTime;
    timeBoxEasy.text = String(Math.ceil((score)/1000));
    var speed:Number = 0.70;
        
        
       for (var i=1; i<=snowBallMCCount; i++) {
          var snowBall = root["snowBallMC"+i];  
              
          if(snowBall.rotation == 0) 
          {
            snowBall.y += -10 * speed;
          }
          
          else 
          {
            snowBall.x += 10 * speed;
          }
       
          if(snowBall.hitTestObject(SantaMC))
          {
            
            //var SantaShotDeadSound = new objectShotDeadSound();
            //SantaShotDeadSound.play();
    
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveSantaMCTowardMouse);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSnowCannonMC1);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shootSnowballCannon);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSnowBallMC);
            
            finalScore= score;
            
            gotoAndPlay(1,"Game Over")
            break;
    
          }
       }
    }
    
    // adding the scores to the highscores table
    
    var scoreTable = SharedObject.getLocal("data"); 
    
    if((scoreTable.data.nameArray==undefined)||(scoreTable.data.scoreArray==undefined)){
        scoreTable.data.nameArray = new Array();
        scoreTable.data.scoreArray = new Array();
    }
    
    function displayScoreTable() {
        sortScores();
        var temp ="LEADERBOARD \n";
        var nameArray = scoreTable.data.nameArray;
        var scoreArray = scoreTable.data.scoreArray;
    
        for (var nameCount = 0; nameCount < nameArray.length; nameCount++) {
            temp += nameArray[nameCount] + " ----- " + String(Math.ceil((scoreArray[nameCount])/1000)) +"\n";
        }
        scoreTableBox.text = temp;
    }
    
    
    function sortScores(){
        
        var nameArray = scoreTable.data.nameArray;
        var scoreArray = scoreTable.data.scoreArray;
        var len = nameArray.length;
        var tempName;
        var tempScore;
            
        for (var count1=0; count1 < len - 1; count1++){
            for (var count2=count1+1; count2 < len; count2++){
                if(scoreArray[count1]<scoreArray[count2]){
                    tempName=nameArray[count1];
                    nameArray[count1]=nameArray[count2];
                    nameArray[count2]=tempName;
                    tempScore=scoreArray[count1];
                    scoreArray[count1]=scoreArray[count2];
                    scoreArray[count2]=tempScore;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try looking for the meaning of #1009 in general? P.S. **File > Publish Settings > Permit Debugging** will let you know the exact line that produced the error.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried debugging the app on Animate CC. It has shown me the line which shows the error, and apparently its one of the navigation button which lets you choose the games difficulty. It works fine until you want to replay the game which is what I don't understand.

Please do throw me some ideas if you could possibly tell where the issue may be.

Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: When you use mouseY like in `SantaMC.x - mouseX;` did you mean `stage.mouseY`? or maybe you already made your own  `var mouseY` definition that is not shown in above code? Also constantly moving around the main timeline is worst way to code. If you make a variable on frame 1 (`var num : int = 10`) then tell stage `gotoAndStop(20)` then at this frame 20 you say `num = 5` now since `num`  existed at frame 1 will frame 20 code know what you mean? Or will there be a _"null object / variable "_ referencing error since it thinks "who/what are you talking about"? Test if this is your issue